# PHP/Javascript: Variable Swapping & Function calling

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am making a small distance finder applet. Basically, I have two variables coming from PHP from the server and they are $Location1 and $Location2. I want to integrate those variables into this Javascript. I want to substitute the variables from PHP into the ones that are found in the Javascript.

That is my main problem. My other problem is that I can't find out how to call Javascript functions into another page. For example I have this Javascript on one page called "DistanceFinder" and I want what this script to execute on another page - similar to calling a function in PHP.

Thanks for your help. I have not had any formal training and I am trying to learn these languages. If you could help me out here it would be awesome. Thanks.

P.S This is using the Google Maps API V3, and the script is from a tutorial on the internet.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Distance finder</title>
<meta type="description" content="Find the distance between two places on the map and the shortest route."/>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var location1;
    var location2;

    var address1;
    var address2;

    var latlng;
    var geocoder;
    var map;

    var distance;

    // finds the coordinates for the two locations and calls the showMap() function
    function initialize()
    {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // creating a new geocode object

        // getting the two address values
        address1 = document.getElementById("address1").value;
        address2 = document.getElementById("address2").value;

        // finding out the coordinates
        if (geocoder) 
        {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address1}, function(results, status) 
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {
                    //location of first address (latitude + longitude)
                    location1 = results[0].geometry.location;
                } else 
                {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address2}, function(results, status) 
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {
                    //location of second address (latitude + longitude)
                    location2 = results[0].geometry.location;
                    // calling the showMap() function to create and show the map 
                    showMap();
                } else 
                {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // creates and shows the map
    function showMap()
    {
        // center of the map (compute the mean value between the two locations)
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng((location1.lat()+location2.lat())/2,(location1.lng()+location2.lng())/2);

        // set map options
            // set zoom level
            // set center
            // map type
        var mapOptions = 
        {
            zoom: 1,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };

        // create a new map object
            // set the div id where it will be shown
            // set the map options
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        // show route between the points
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
        {
            suppressMarkers: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: true
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        var request = {
            origin:location1, 
            destination:location2,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                distance = "The distance between the two points on the chosen route is: "+response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
                distance += "<br/>The aproximative driving time is: "+response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
                document.getElementById("distance_road").innerHTML = distance;
            }
        });

        // show a line between the two points
        var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: map, 
            path: [location1, location2],
            strokeWeight: 7,
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeColor: "#FFAA00"
        });

        // create the markers for the two locations     
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: location1,
            title: "First location"
        });
        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: location2,
            title: "Second location"
        });

        // create the text to be shown in the infowindows
        var text1 = '<div id="content">'+
                '<h1 id="firstHeading">First location</h1>'+
                '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                '<p>Coordinates: '+location1+'</p>'+
                '<p>Address: '+address1+'</p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';

        var text2 = '<div id="content">'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading">Second location</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p>Coordinates: '+location2+'</p>'+
            '<p>Address: '+address2+'</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';

        // create info boxes for the two markers
        var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: text1
        });
        var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: text2
        });

        // add action events so the info windows will be shown when the marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
            infowindow1.open(map,marker1);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
            infowindow2.open(map,marker1);
        });

        // compute distance between the two points
        var R = 6371; 
        var dLat = toRad(location2.lat()-location1.lat());
        var dLon = toRad(location2.lng()-location1.lng()); 

        var dLat1 = toRad(location1.lat());
        var dLat2 = toRad(location2.lat());

        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.cos(dLat1) * Math.cos(dLat1) * 
                Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
        var d = R * c;

        document.getElementById("distance_direct").innerHTML = "<br/>The distance between the two points (in a straight line) is: "+d;
    }

    function toRad(deg) 
    {
        return deg * Math.PI/180;
    }
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <div id="form" style="width:100%; height:20%">
        <table align="center" valign="center">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" align="center"><b>Find the distance between two locations</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>First address:</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" size="50"/></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Second address:</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" size="50"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" align="center"><input type="button" value="Show" onClick="initialize();"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <center><div style="width:100%; height:10%" id="distance_direct"></div></center>
    <center><div style="width:100%; height:10%" id="distance_road"></div></center>

    <center><div id="map_canvas" style="width:70%; height:54%"></div></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code you wrote is a php file...

```
var location1 = "<?php echo $Location1 ?>";
var location2 = "<?php echo $Location2 ?>";
```

That said, this will stop you from minimizing and putting this javascript into a separate JavaScript file(which you should do at some point).

> My other problem is that I can't find out how to call Javascript
>   functions into another page. For example I have this Javascript on one
>   page called "DistanceFinder" and I want what this script to execute on
>   another page - similar to calling a function in PHP.

Don't think of JavaScript as belonging to a certain page. Start separating your JavaScript code into separate js files so they don't clutter up your html/php files. If you want to call a function from some other JavaScript you wrote just include its .js file in the page you want to call it from.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/myCode.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, the bit about embedding it into PHP did not work, however the functions explanation really helped. I don't have edit privellages or I would have corrected it (from the post below), but otherwise this post really helped me. Thank you.

Comment: it was the code, it should have been var location1 = "<?php echo $Location1 ?>";
var location2 = "<?php echo $Location2 ?>"; That's just a minor thing though.

Comment: Also, quick question - can I still embed the PHP in a .js file like above?

Comment: @tushar747 I had quotes originally but i thought location was going to be a number. Anyways, you really shouldn't embed php variables directly into JavaScript as it will cause you issues when you move on to more complex projects. What you can do though is write functions that take parameters and call those functions from your php page to pass the php variables ie initialize(<?php echo $variable?>). The other thing that you might start looking into is javascript frameworks like jQuery. You can start using AJAX calls to get the needed data from php and use it in your JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that aspect of jQuery now. It seems really useful, and I've just started coding so I'm still learning all of this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var mylocationvar = "<?php echo $location1;?>";
```

Or even better:

```
var mylocationvar = <?= json_encode($location1); ?>;
```

Comment: The first one worked great! Thanks. I was half way there - I just didn't have the quotation marks..